# Validate values with invalid format in ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

On an ASP.NET Core 2.2 API I have the following action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody]Model model) {
}
```

Where `Model` is the following:

```
public class Model { 
  public DateTime? PublishedAt { get; set; }       
}
```

Property `PublishedAt` is required and needs to be in the past.

When calling the action I am able to predict 2 different scenarios:

1. Data sent to action doesn't include `PublishedAt` or `PublishedAt` is NULL.

   By using `DateTime?` I am able to check if it is NULL or in the past in case it is defined.

   **Does this make sense?**
2. Data sent to action includes an invalid `PublishedAt` date (2019-20-40).

   In this case I realised that `Model` becomes null so I cannot validate it.

   I also cannot send back a friendly message such as:

   "Publish At date format is invalid"

   **How can I return friendly messages when a DateTime has wrong format?**

   I would like to avoid using String as data type for `PublishedAt`.

   Maybe using a custom Model Binder?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to put `Required` attribute on `PublishedAt`

```
public class Model 
{ 
    [Required]
    public DateTime? PublishedAt { get; set; }       
}

[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
   public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody]Model model) 
   {
   }
}
```

If you have ApiController attribute on your controller it should automatically respond with BadRequest if it's not present.

Similarly you can add your own custom validation attribute with a message. Asp.Net [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-attributes) has an example on how to do that.

Comment: That's not the point ... I would like to send a error message if PublishedAt is defined but something like "2018400sdsd" which is invalid. In that case validation does not fire because the error is before. In the binding.

Comment: If you want to accept anything and define your own message, you can change type to string and validate that it is in correct format, though there are probably better ways. Though if you have required on a datetime, you will not get a null, there will be an error returned to the client since a parameter is required but it cannot be parsed

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I need but without using Strings ... :-) ... It seems that when using FromBody the JSonParser is responsible for binding and if it fails once it stops and it does not create a partial model with the values that are valid ... I am trying to go around that. Any idea?

Comment: I get this error with required if I send bad input: "Could not convert string to DateTime: 2019-01dd-01. Path 'publishedAt', line 2, position 31." Is that not enough? Do you want to return a custom message?

Comment: Try adding another property to your model, for example "String Title". If you submit a valid Title with a Invalid PublishedAt date you will see that model becomes null. I would like to return 2 errors saying "PublishedAt data has invalid format" and still being able to validate Title.

Comment: I have just done that, I still get the same error, are you sure you have `ApiController` attribute? The model does not validate itself automatically, you either have to do Model.IsValid or use the attribute

Comment: Sure you can see the error but you cannot validate Title. I would like to return the PublishedAt error along with a error for title in case Title length is greater than 20 for example.

Comment: I see what you mean now, you should probably extend the question with these details to make it clear. It seems that as you say the binder intercepts before any validation attributes and returns its error and stops processing

Comment: I assume the correct way for you to go is to use a custom model binder. That way it'll be a bit clumsy, but you can achieve what you want with it I think: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2. You can use `bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError` to add your custom error.

Answer (score 0):

> IMHO, I like the approach below and have used it extensively without any problems. The good thing about this approach is that it keeps your model clean and enables separation of concerns. Your validation logic for the `Model` is completely independent.

Try using `FluentValidation`. You can read about it [here](https://fluentvalidation.net/aspnet) in detail. It's a NuGet package that you can [download](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation.AspNetCore/) via NuGet.org. Once installed you can register it in `ConfigureServices` like below:

```
1 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
2 {
3    services.AddMvc(setup => {
4      //...mvc setup...
5    }).AddFluentValidation(configuration => configuration
6      .RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());
7 }
```

Line number 5 and 6 will automatically find any public, non-abstract types that inherit from `AbstractValidator` and register them with the container. You then define your `AbstractValidator` for `Model` as below

Before you create your `AbstractValidator`

> I know you mentioned that you would want to avoid changing the PublishedAt type to string. However, I would suggest you consider it. That will make it easy to validate the parameter, otherwise, automatic model binding may bind it in a different format, and custom model binding is little trickier than the following.
>
> If you really want to avoid changing the `PublishedAt` to `string`,
>   you can try the same approach by changing the rules slightly and see
>   if that works for you

```
public class ModelValidator : AbstractValidator<Model>
{
    public ModelValidator()
    {
        // add a rule that Date must be in the past, shouldn't be empty
        // and in the correct format
        RuleFor(model => model.PublishedAt)
           .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
           .Must(date => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(date))
               .WithMessage("PublishAt is a required parameter")
           .Must(arg =>
           {
               if (DateTime.TryParseExact(arg.ToString(), new[] { "dd-MMM-yyyy" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime date))
               {
                   return date < DateTime.Now;
               }

               return false;
            })
            .When(model => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.PublishedAt))
            .WithMessage("Argument PublishAt is invalid. Please specify the date in dd-MMM-yyy and should be in the past");
    }
}
```

The above validator will be executed after the model binding process and if the validation fails, `WithMessage` statements will add the error to the ModelState. As you have `[ApiController]` attribute. Your model will be validated and it will return the messages you specified in the `WithMessage` statements.

Or you can manually check if the `ModelState.IsValid` inside the action method and return the `ObjectResult` with the ModelState.

Comment: I am using exactly what you are using, including FluentValidation, but I would like to avoid using String for DateTime properties like PublishedAt. So I am trying to merge the ASP.NET Core ModelBinder errors with FluentValidation errors. But I think there is a problem which is Newtonsoft Json which does not create Partial Models. So on errors it does not go to Fluent Validation.

Comment: ok, try changing the `PublishedAt` to be simple `DateTime` instead of `DateTime?`. In the Validator, add a Rule that checks for MinDate, instead of null or empty. So if it's Minimum, which means that it hasn't been passed to the request.