# Return Model Binding errors and Fluent Validation errors in single BadRequest

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-2.0, fluentvalidation

On an ASP.NET Core 2.2 ApiController I have the following action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody]Model model) {

}
```

Where `Model` is the following:

```
public class Model { 
  public String Title { get; set; }
  public DateTime? PublishedAt { get; set; }       
}
```

I am using `FluentValidation` to validate the model:

```
public class ModelValidator : AbstractValidator<Model> {

  public ModelValidator() {

    RuleFor(x => x.Title).NotEmpty().MaximumLength(80);

    RuleFor(x => x.PublishedAt).NotNull().Must(x => x < DateTime.Now);

  }

}
```

When `PublishedAt` is invalid, for example `2019-40-80`, `ModelValidator` does not run ...

This is because Validation in ASP.NET Core follows, if I am not wrong, the order:

1. Model Binding

   Returns a Bad Request with errors that occurred in Model Binding.
   For example, if it can't bind `2019-40-80` to a DateTime? property.
2. Fluent Validation (When used)
3. Default ASP.NET Core

The problem is in "**1. Model Binding**" where when using `[FromBody]` which is common on an API.

When using `[FromBody]` NewtonSoft is responsible for parsing the body JSON.

If it fails then returns the errors with BadRequest and ModelValidator is not called.

I have been trying with the following on ConfigureServices:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(x => {

  x.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = false;

  x.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = y => {

    var errors = y.ModelState
      .Where(e => e.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
      .Select(e => new {
        Name = e.Key,
        Message = e.Value.Errors.First().ErrorMessage
      }).ToArray();

    return new BadRequestObjectResult(errors);

  };

});
```

But no luck ...

**Question**

How to return Model Binding errors and Fluent Validation errors in single BadRequest?

Is there a way to configure Newtonsoft to create a partial Model?

Comment: As per [this](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/175) issue, it's not possible. Although the post is old, I don't think there is any change in the original behaviour. That's why I suggested you to consider changing the `PublishedAt` type to string in your original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55925199/validate-values-with-invalid-format-in-asp-net-core-api/55929623?noredirect=1#comment98523725_55929623)

Comment: Yes, I know that String would solve the problem. But then this also happens in Ints, Doubles, and so on ... Which means I would use Strings in all models and need to parse things everywhere which seems strange and unnecessary extra work and complexity added to the application. That is why I am trying for solutions and already suggesting options to ASP.NET core team in Github

Comment: Yes true, please do share the options that you are suggesting to ASP.NET core team

Comment: I basically suggested that any error during Model Binding should keep being added to Model State but the Model should still be created with the properties that were parsed. This way the process would carry on to Fluent Validation and Annotation Validation where other validation errors would be added to Model State. Finally, using the recent InvalidModelStateResponseFactory added in ASP.NET Core 2.2 a BadRequest could be returned in any chosen form.

Comment: I also suggested adding a Flag property to ModelState errors to indicate the origin of each error: Model Binding or Model Validation. That way it would be possible to take decisions also based on what originated an error.

Comment: Do you find this a reasonable approach? The issue is here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9856. Please give your feedback to.

Comment: I have been checking Newtonsoft JSON to find out if there is an option to create a partial model even if deserialisation errors occurred. I think this is not possible but maybe with the new JSON engine to be included in ASP.NET Core 3 this could be a reality.

Comment: I think, when the model binding error occurs they can create a model by utilising `dynamic` or `ExpandoObject`. Only if there is some sort of ModelValidation present i.e. FluentValidation or DataAnnotations.  You can use that dynamic model to check if there are ModelBinding errors or not. Then combine it with your custom ModelValidation and may be Merge or modify the ModelState.